# Error while compiling module to kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, ssl

I am trying to compile e1000e module on Ubuntu 16.10 to kernel.
It's kernel is: 4.8.0-26-generic.
I am running the command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules_install
```

However I get this error:

```
At main.c:158:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c$
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory.
```

I was able do just run:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules.
```

On older kernels ( like 4.1) I was able to compile the module to the kernel.
Has someone encountered this problem while compiling other modules to the kernel? Does anybody know how to solve this?

Edit: I tried to compile on the same kernel igb driver and got the same message, the same thing occurred on fedora with kernel 4.8*.